# How to configure Crashlytics with iOS manually? - Fabric.io magic doesn't work

Tags: ios, xcode, crashlytics, fabric.io

I'm using Xcode 6.3. Just downloaded Fabric.io and I'm trying to install Crashlytics to one of my apps.

I've added the build phase script and ran the Build as it asked me to.

Then I dragged the SDKs folder into the Project Navigator and clicked on the Finish button. I now see `Fabric.framework` and `Crashlytics.framework` in my project.

However, the Fabric app doesn't see that I've done the last step. It's still asking me to install the SDK Kits.

How do I proceed?

Thanks

Comment: Hey, Alex here from Fabric. Can you try clearing your cache by running "rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/com.crashlytics.mac" and then building and running your app again? If that doesn't work, I can dig into this more- just let me know your bundle id or email in at support@fabric.io!

Comment: Alex, thanks. I figured out the problem. When I added the build script, the selected target was my appTest instead of app.
But now Fabric says that it cannot find the app I'm trying to onboard and that I need to contact support@fabric.io

Comment: Hi Alex, I'm having a similar problem. The difference is I can't even build my app after creating the Run Script Build Phase. I receive a dSYM error instructing me to set DEBUG_INFORMATION_FORMAT to "DWARF with dSYM File". The problem is it's already on that setting but the app still does not build. I'm running Xcode 6.3 as well. Tried your advice of running rm -rf but that didn't work either. Any idea on what's causing this?

Comment: @swbandit running "rm -rf ~/Library/Caches/com.crashlytics.mac", building and running _should_ fix your issue.

Comment: @timshim I just sent you an email about this - I'm going to have to dig into your specific configuration.

Answer (score 2):

In your app delegate did you do:
Swift:

```
import Fabric
import Crashlytics

func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
    ...
    Fabric.with([Crashlytics()])
    ...
}
```

Obj-C:

```
#import <Fabric/Fabric.h>
#import <Crashlytics/Crashlytics.h>

- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {
    [Fabric with:@[CrashlyticsKit]];
    ...
}
```

Comment: No I didn't. But when I add `Fabric.with([Crashlytics()])` I get a `signal SIGABRT` crash. Also, the Fabric app is still waiting for me to install the SDKs.

Comment: Are you writing in objc?

Comment: I have the same problem @swbandit Could you do it?

Answer (score 1):

Well the Question's author solved his problem by adding the Target. I had the same problem while trying to add Fabric to an iOS 11 app on xCode 9. I solved the problem by adding the Crashlytics and Fabric frameworks in **General** under the **Linked Frameworks and Libraries**